# XmlSerialization won't work

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xml, serialization

We are currently developping an application using XmlSerializer from the .NET framework.

Here is the structure of our classes:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(TimeLineMediaClass))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ImageMediaClass))]
public abstract class MediaClass
{
    public string filename { get; set; }
    public string maintitle { get; set; }
    public string subtitle { get; set; }
    public Type typeOfMedia { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(AudioMediaClass))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(VideoMediaClass))]
public abstract class TimeLineMediaClass : MediaClass
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan length { get; set; }
    public string genre { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class AudioMediaClass : TimeLineMediaClass
{
    public string artist { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class VideoMediaClass : TimeLineMediaClass
{
    public string director { get; set; }
    public string studios { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class ImageMediaClass : MediaClass
{
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
}
```

Several medias of different types are added to a List, and this is what we want to serialize.

This is how the serializer is instanciated:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MediaClass>));
```

But when we launch the program and try to serialize, an exception is thrown, stating that "AudioMediaClass was not expected".

EDIT: A few things were missing in the code I have provided. I have added some corrections in it ; more details in comments.

Comment: This seems to be xml name space issue(xmlns). Do you use xmlns anywhere in the attribute. If yes, remove it and see if it works

Comment: Where are the ImageMediaClass?

Comment: Hey John, you solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks to both of you for answering. Regarding the mispelling of "TimeLineMediaClass" and the missing "ImageMediaClass", it was because I typed them manually, as I did not included them in the copy-paste. I made the appropriate corrections above. Sorry for the late answer, I was kind of busy.

Comment: And regarding the `xmlns` suggestion by Dipesh Bhatt, we do not use this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decorate your `MediaClass` class with

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(TimeLineMediaClass))]
```

In your example above, you have the casing wrong on `TimelineMediaClass` meaning the sample won't compile for me. If you remove it, or if you *do* have a *different* class with this name, you'll get the error you describe.

Once you correct the casing, it should work - it does for me [noting that I also had to remove the attribute for `ImageMediaClass` which also doesn't exist in your sample].

Answer (score 0):

I copy your code, and run removing `[XmlInclude(typeof(ImageMediaClass))]` and correcting this attribute: `[XmlInclude(typeof(TimelineMediaClass))]` to `[XmlInclude(typeof(TimeLineMediaClass))]`. Now, running your code, it works fine.